# Apply transform property on a special element

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a button with a notification bubble on it. I applied a hover property on this button in order to enlarge the button. The problem is that the notification on the button is also transformed and it caused a tiny space between button and notification.
How can I make to have a uniform transformation between my button and my notification on it? I am aware that the position of the notifications is in pixels and maybe this is the origin of the problem.

Here's my code:

```css
    .notify-badge{
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #3bb2bc !important;
     height: 25px;
     width: 25px;
     right: 40px;
     bottom: 40px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 25px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     color: white;
     border:1px solid #3bb2bc;
    }

    a {
     background: white;
     padding: 15px;
     padding-top: 11px;
     border: 0;
     border-radius: 50%;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     margin-left: 30px;
    }

    a:hover{
     transform: scale(1.1);
     transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    }
```

```html
    <a class="button">
     <img src="images.png"/>
     <span class="notify-badge">2</span>
    </a>
```

Comment: Please provide all the code necessary to replicate the issue.

Comment: using `a:hover img {` instead of `a:hover {`  will only scale the image, if that is what you are after